# Jquery Display Message then Ajax then hide message

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

il give an example

```
document.ready(function() {
    $("#Show").bind("click", function() 
    {
        var F = Function2();
        if (F)
        {
            // Do Other Stuff.
        }
    }
});

function Function2()
{
    $("#Message").Show();

    $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
               url: [MyURL]
               async: false;
               contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
               data: JSON.stringify(PostData),
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (returnVal) {
           $("#Message").Hide();
                   return true;
               },
               error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                   return false;
               }
           });

}

</script>




<div id="Message" style="display:none;">
    <!-- Loading Image In here -->
</div>
<a href="#" id="Show" onclick="return:false;">Show then Hide</false>
</code>
```

Now what I want to happen is for this messagebox to show however the AJAX for some reason wont show it until the AJAX Request is finished by which point it is too late.  I have set async to false which hasent helped either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the root of this issue is a syntax error. JavaScript is case sensitive, so the correct syntax would be lowercase `show()` and `hide()`

If you're still having an issue after fixing the syntax errors, try using the `ajaxStart` event to show the message and hide it on success.

```
//use the ajaxstart event to display the message
$('#message').ajaxStart(function() {
    $(this).show("slow");
});

$.ajax({   
    type: "POST",   
    url: [MyURL]   
    async: false;   
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',   
    data: JSON.stringify(PostData),   
    dataType: "json",   
    success: function (returnVal) {   
        $("#Message").hide("slow"); //hide message on success   
        return true;   
    },   
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {   
        return false;   
    }   
});
```

#### Delaying the show or hide

```
$("#message").delay(3000).hide("slow");
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rs83R/

Comment: Problem is the message doesent show at all it just runs the AJAX Code then displays the message when the ajax completes.  I need the image to show then run the ajax then hide the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding the Message div in the click event after getting true or false.

Remove the async:false, I do not think that is anyway relevant to fixing this problem. The purpose of AJAX call is to make an asynchronous call.

Also, there is an error its not $("#Message").Show() its $("#Message").show() with all lowercase, same goes for hide().

Try changing these, I hope it should work.